# opencv 3.0.0 java imread_0 undefined

Tags: scala, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to develop an application using java opencv 3.0.0-beta using scala.

I am getting a runtime error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

While researching the cause i have created the following simple application the exhibits similar behaviour:

```
import reflect._

import org.opencv.core.Core
import org.opencv.core.Mat
import org.opencv.core.CvType
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs

object main extends Application {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)

    val what = "something.png"
      val mat = Imgcodecs.imread(what)
      Imgcodecs.imwrite("something_else.png", mat)
}
```

The major difference is that, if run as "sbt run" it performs as expected. if the appropriate lines are removed from the above the code fails in REPL.

I suspect that this issue is related to the original issue, but have no proof.

If i look at the memory map of the JVM in both cases i have the expected libs loaded.

If the code is inspected i find no definition of org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1

I am quite lost as to where to go next in diagnosing this issue.

Is there anyone who has come across this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try: String what = "something.png"; Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imread(what); instead of using "val" type?

Comment: Thanks Ha Dang. no i haven't. coding it in java just did not occur to me. the bulk of the real app is scala.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't used openCV3.0 yet, as it has major changes and breaks opencv 2.4.x code , are you supplying the library path to

```
sbt run
```

add

```
javaOptions in run += "-Djava.library.path=lib/opencv/"
```

to your build.sbt file or pass on cmd line

```
sbt run -Djava.library.path=lib/opencv/
```

opencv folder should have your files that gets generated along with your jar file

i have java  bindins for 2.4.9 , 2.4.10 and 3.0.0 for java 7 and 8 in this git repo if you need them

```
git@gitlab.com:opencv/java_lib.git
```

Comment: Thanks DAR. This doesn't seem to be my problem, as the libraries are present when i look at the process map ( cat /proc/{pid}/maps)